# Decompiling animated GIF file within an app

Tags: android

I would like to download a animated GIF file (more specifically, a weather radar loop), decompile it in frames and play the contents via AnimationDrawable.

The latter part and downloading the image is not a problem, but the middle part is puzzling me: how on earth can I extract the separate frames from the GIF within an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy to use [GifDecoder](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/GiffileEncoder.htm) that did the trick for me.